# Project Euler 29

Tags: c

Here's the question

Consider all integer combinations of a^b for 2 ≤ a ≤ 5 and 2 ≤ b ≤ 5:

```
2^2=4, 2^3=8, 2^4=16, 2^5=32
3^2=9, 3^3=27, 3^4=81, 3^5=243
4^2=16, 4^3=64, 4^4=256, 4^5=1024
5^2=25, 5^3=125, 5^4=625, 5^5=3125
```

If they are then placed in numerical order, with any repeats removed, we get the following sequence of 15 distinct terms:

4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, 64, 81, 125, 243, 256, 625, 1024, 3125

How many distinct terms are in the sequence generated by a^b for 2 ≤ a ≤ 100 and 2 ≤ b ≤ 100?

And here's my code

```
int b[10000][300]={};
int a[10000][300]={};
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,k=0,z;
    int ticker=2;
    int carry=0,oi=0;
    int carry1=0,count=0;
    for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        a[i][0]=1;
    }

    for(k=0;k<100;k++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<300;j++)
            {   
                carry1=(ticker*a[k][j]+carry)/10;
                a[k][j]=(ticker*a[k][j]+carry)%10;
                carry=carry1;
            }
            for(z=0;z<300;z++)
            {
                b[oi][z]=a[k][z]; // Storing the number, everytime its multiplied
            }
            oi++;
            carry1=0;
            carry=0;
        }
        ticker++;
    }
    int l=0,flag=0,blue=0;
    for(z=0;z<9900;z++)
    {

        for(i=0;i<9900;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<205;j++)
            {
                if(b[z][j]!=b[i][j])
                {
                    blue++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(blue==9899)
        {
            l++;
        }
        blue=0;
    }
    printf("\n%d\n",l-99);
    return(0);
}
```

And here's my explanation.
Since C can't handle large numbers, I decided to store every number that you get by a^b in an array by devising an algorithm for multiplication. Ie i store the digits of that number in an array.
I then check which of the numbers in the array are the same and eliminate them.
It's simple. But somehow I'm not getting the right answer which is 9183, and have looked at my code several times but can't find the glitch
Help me out guys. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you're counting the *unique* numbers in the last loop-block. That means you don't count things like 16 = 2^4 = 4^2 = 16^1 at all.

You can solve this problem with plain `int` if you instead count the duplicates without calculating them (just a small hint to not spoil the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is in the bounds of the loops.
for example, you store the numbers after one iterate of multiplication, which mean (n^1).
I suggest you to reduce variables. the code will than be more readable, and the potential of mistakes will go down.